# Android: Push notification from server on change in database (not using GCM)

Tags: android, push-notification

I have set up my app and database.
If I restart activity (startActivity(getIntent()) or going back and forth), my listview gets updated.
But, it is not autorefreshing.
I am not using GCM for my application,but a database hosted on some other web server.

I am stuck at how to get notified if there is any new entry in database and get a push notification on screen.

(Please share resources/tutorials if anybody knows)

Comment: if you dont want to use GCM look into xmpp

Comment: Thanks. I am using GCM now. Looks like it is easier way to achieve what I was trying to do